# How to have a global variable in Jmeter for Inter thread communication?

Tags: multithreading, variables, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I want to have a global variable for inter thread communication.

Current setup:

Thread Group 1: It is a multi-user thread, that will be accessing certain API's in a flow.

Thread group 2: Now, as per our current system, the auth-token refreshes after every 10 min. So in this thread group, I am calling refreshToken API.

Approach1: Tried using jmeter property. But since all threads are in parallel, so if one thread updates the token, all other threads fail.

Approach2: Using InterThreadCommunication plugin. Since I don't know when and where in the system, the token will expire, so don't know where to call in the inter thread communication pre-processor.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use thread-specific properties like:

1. In "Refresh Token" Thread Group specify individual properties to hold tokens for each virtual user like:

   ```
   ${__setProperty(token_${__threadNum},YOUR_TOKEN_VALUE_HERE,)}
   ```
2. In "PA APIs" Thread Group access individual token values like:

   ```
   ${__P(token_${__threadNum},)}
   ```

References:

- [__setProperty() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty)
- [__threadNum() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum)
- [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction)

Answer (score 0):

In approach 1 with jmeter property you can continue with adding a [Critical Section Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Critical_Section_Controller) with same key as a parent for Samplers who is trying to get or refresh your token.

That way Threads will wait until previous (get/)update token will be over and then get the updated token.

Notice that it won't work in Distributed testing:

> Critical Section Controller takes locks only within one JVM, so if using Distributed testing ensure your use case does not rely on all threads of all JVMs blocking.

Comment: But this means that all other threads will have to wait, until one is completing? Coz as per sscreenshot, you can see that getToken works once, and then all other requests use that token.

Comment: This is your requirement to wait until get new token

Comment: Maybe I put it in a wrong way. Sorry for that. My requirement is - That all threads run in parallel. Token is unique to each thread. Refresh token, needs to run in parallel and refresh each unique token as well.

Comment: If it's per thread you can just set JMeter variable with new token value